# How to find list of item under div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**I have the following code:**

[![

```html
<div id="s2id_location" class="select2-container location req" style="width: 550px;">
<a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span id="select2-chosen-1" class="select2-chosen">Current location</span>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"/>
<span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
<b role="presentation"/>
</span>
</a>
<label class="select2-offscreen" for="s2id_autogen1"/>
<input id="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-1" tabindex="0"/>
</div>
<select id="location" name="currentloc" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Current location</option>
<option value="1">Ahmedabad</option>
<option value="2">Bengaluru / Bangalore</option>
<option value="3">Chennai</option>
<option value="4">Delhi</option>
<option value="5">Gurgaon</option>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ0em.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ0em.png)

How do i access Gurgaon from above the code.

Comment: This is not a java question

Comment: its a selenium webdriver question using java language.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath something like this

```
//select[@name='currentloc']/option[@value='5']
```

OR

```
//select[@name='currentloc']/option[contains(text(),'Gurgaon')]
```

Select any one from above and put in the below code

```
String loc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='currentloc']/option[@value='5']")).gettext();
system.out.print(loc);
```

Try above both xpaths

Answer (score -1):

```
String elementval = driver.findElement(By.id("location")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: That's not going to work. Getting value will return whatever is currently selected and "Current location" is most likely selected when the page is first loaded.